# How to know if Sharepoint 2013 List is registered to Remote Event Receiver in Provider Hosted App?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I have multiple list in SharePoint 2013 and some of the lists are attached to ListEvent.svc service. I would like to know which specific lists are registered to that particular Remote Event Receiver?

I know we can get it programmatically using "properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle" but are there any XML files generated wherein it contains all the lists name attached to a particular service.